# SICP solution to Fibonacci, set `a + b = a`, why not `a + b = b`?

Tags: algorithm, lisp, elisp, fibonacci, sicp

I am reading [Tree Recursion](https://mitpress.mit.edu/sites/default/files/sicp/full-text/book/book-Z-H-11.html#%_sec_1.2.2) of SICP, where  `fib` was computed by a linear recursion.

> We can also formulate an iterative process for computing the
>   Fibonacci numbers. The idea is to use a pair of integers *a* and *b*,
>   initialized to *Fib(1) = 1* and *Fib(0) = 0*, and to repeatedly apply the
>   simultaneous transformations

[image]

> It is not hard to show that, after applying this transformation *n*
>   times, *a* and *b* will be equal, respectively, to *Fib(n + 1)* and *Fib(n)*.
>   Thus, we can compute Fibonacci numbers iteratively using the procedure

(rewrite by Emacs Lisp substitute for Scheme)

> ```
> #+begin_src emacs-lisp :session sicp 
> (defun fib-iter (a b count)
>   (if (= count 0)
>       b
>       (fib-iter (+ a b) a (- count 1))))
>
> (defun fib (n)
>   (fib-iter 1 0 n))
>
> (fib 4)
> #+end_src
> ```

*"Set `a + b = a` and `b = a`"*, it's hard to wrap my mind around it.

The general idea to find a `fib` is simple:

Suppose a completed Fibonacci number table, search `X` in  the table by jumping step by step from `0` to `X`.

The solution is barely intuitive.

It's reasonably to set `a + b = b`, `a = b`:

```
(defun fib-iter (a b count)
  (if (= count 0)
      a
      (fib-iter b (+ a b) (- count 1))
  )
)
(defun fib(n)
  (fib-iter 0 1 n))
```

So, the authors' setting seems no more than just anti-intuitively placing `b` in the head with  no special purpose.

However, I surely acknowledge that SICP deserves digging deeper and deeper.

What key points am I missing? Why set `a + b = a` rather than `a + b = b`?

Comment: What meaning do you give to "Set `a + b = a`" ???

Comment: I can see that the first version comes from the book.  Is the second version your own variant, with the question being "why didn't the book do it my way?"

Comment: yes, it's anti-intuitive to place bigger number ahead of the smaller. `fit-iter(1, 0, )`, so desire to make sure whether there exist dedicated consideration within. @phils

Comment: I do not know the answer.  I can only speculate that the authors did not consider their solution to be as unintuitive as you have found it.  Different minds think differently.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I can see your problem is that you don't like it that order of the arguments to `fib-iter` is not what you think it should be.  The answer is that the order of arguments to functions is very often simply arbitrary and/or conventional: it's a choice made by the person writing the function.  It does not matter to anyone but the person reading or writing the code: it's a stylistic choice.  It doesn't particularly seem more intuitive to me to have `fib` defined as

```
(define (fib n)
  (fib-iter 1 0 n))

(define (fib-iter next current n)
  (if (zero? n)
      current
      (fib-iter (+ next current) next (- n 1))))
```

Rather than

```
(define (fib n)
  (fib-iter 0 1 n))

(define (fib-iter current next n)
  (if (zero? n)
      current
      (fib-iter (+ next current) current (- n 1))))
```

There are instances where this isn't true.  For instance [Standard Lisp](http://user.ceng.metu.edu.tr/~ucoluk/research/lisp/sl.pdf) (warning, PDF link) defined `mapcar` so that the list being mapped over was the *first* argument with the function being mapped the second.  This means you can't extend it in the way it has been extended for more recent dialects, so that it takes any positive number of lists with the function being applied to the
corresponding elements of all the lists.

Similarly I think it would be extremely unintuitive to define the arguments of `-` or `/` the other way around.

but in many, many cases it's just a matter of making a choice and sticking to it.

Answer (score 2):

The recurrence is given in an imperative form. For instance, in Common Lisp, we could use *parallel assignment* in the body of a loop:

```
(psetf a (+ a b) 
       b a)
```

To reduce confusion, we should think about this functionally and give the old and new variables different names:

> a = a' + b'
>
> b = a'

This is no longer an assignment but a pair of equalities; we are justified in using the ordinary "**=**" operator of mathematics instead of the assignment arrow.

The linear recursion does this implicitly, because it avoids assignment. The value of the expression `(+ a b)` is passed as the parameter `a`. But that's a fresh instance of `a` in new scope which uses the same name, not an assignment; the binding just induces the two to be equivalent.

We can see it also like this with the help of a "Fibonacci slide rule":

```
    1  1  2  3  5  8  13
    ----------------------------- <-- sliding interface
             b' a' 
                b  a
```

As we calculate the sequence, there is a two-number window whose entries we are calling *a* and *b*, which slides along the sequence. You can read the equalities at any position directly off the slide rule: look, *b* = *a'* = 5 and *a* = *b'* + *a'* = 8.

You may be confused by *a* referring to the higher position in the sequence. You might be thinking of this labeling:

```
    1  1  2  3  5  8  13
    ------------------------
             a' b'
                a  b
```

Indeed, under this naming arrangement, now we have *b* = *a'* + *b'*, as you expect, and *a* = *b'*.

It's just a matter of which variable is designated as the leading one farther along the sequence, and which is the trailing one.

The "*a* is leading" convention comes from the idea that *a* is before *b* in the alphabet, and so it receives the newer "updates" from the sequence first, which then pass off to *b*.

This may seem counterintuitive, but such a pattern appears elsewhere in mathematics, such as [convolution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convolution) of functions.

Comment: `a` being the head making total sense, we still have two substantially different readings of this. one is recursion as in the book, counting down from *n* to *0*. the other is *corecursion*, counting *up* from 0 to *whatever*! and in fact, any iterative algo counting from *0* to *n*  is a step towards the corecursive one, IMO (if not already practically equivalent to it). :)